# `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` forgets session when Chrome quits

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I've made a Chrome extension and I use `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` to authenticate to my own server which uses Facebook as a provider (using an Elixir/Phoenix server and the `pow` and `pow_assent` libraries).  The authentication works fine, but when Chrome quits (tested on Mac and Windows) the session is forgotten and the user needs to go into my plugin's popup and go through the authentication process again.

I've searched and searched and have found no solution.  Do I need to do something special to have it remember the authentication when the browser is quit and re-opened?

Comment: You'll need to save the user session in a cookie. Take a look at this video: https://youtu.be/NxHVnK00Q6k